# kinda stuck in using scale() property while hovering image

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have this image which is inside div with `class="image-wrapper"`. All I am trying to do is:

1. display `.image-wrapper::before` while being hovered on image so it works like title of image
2. also use `transform: scale(1.1)` on img so it grows little on being hovered

##### Description of problem from my side

> In order to display title inside image (part 1), using `::before`, we cannot use it directly on `img` as they are replaced elements, so I enclosed `img` with `div` with `class="image-wrapper"` and used `::before` on `div`. And it worked fine as I expected. Now for the second part, I am not able to render both property same time. I am kinda confused.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper::before {
  content: 'Hello';
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 240, 0.3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*HERE IS THE PROBLEM*/

.image-wrapper:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624215824600-ed3118b76873?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDMwfDZzTVZqVExTa2VRfHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of all there in your code, but the before pseudo element wont show up above its element, unless you give it a higher `z-index`.

Also this snippet slightly alters the CSS so that what it's looking for is hover on the `image-wrapper` class both for the Hello and the `img` scaling.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper::before {
  content: 'Hello';
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  background: pink margin-left: 8px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 240, 0.3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-wrapper:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624215824600-ed3118b76873?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDMwfDZzTVZqVExTa2VRfHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
</div>
```

Comment: @A Haworth Thanks for that . I have edited my code for adding `border: 2px solid black; `  on `.image-wrapper` class and after adding border why is there that ugly padding coming at the bottom of image. This border is perfectly over every side expect at the bottom where some padding is being shown. Check that one as well please

Comment: This is a different question.